# harmonic series with x86-64 assembly

Tags: x86-64, nasm, calculus

Trying to compute a harmonic series.

Right now I'm entering the number I want the addition to go up to.

When I enter a small number like 1.2, the program just stops, doesn't crash, it seems to be doing calculations.

BUt it never finishes the program

here is my code

```
denominator:
xor r14,r14             ;zero out r14 register
add r14, 2              ;start counter at 2
fld1                    ;load 1 into st0
fxch    st2
denomLoop:
fld1    
mov [divisor], r14              ;put 1 into st0
fidiv   dword [divisor]         ;divide st0 by r14
inc r14             ;increment r14
fst qword [currentSum]      ;pop current sum value into currentSum
jmp addParts
addParts:
fld qword [currentSum]
fadd    st2     ;add result of first division to 1
fxch    st2             ;place result of addition into st2
fld qword [realNumber]          ;place real number into st0
;compare to see if greater than inputed value
fcom    st2             ;compare st0 with st2
fstsw   ax              ;needed to do floating point comparisons on FPU
sahf                    ;needed to do floating point comaprisons on FPU
jg  done                ;jump if greater than
jmp denomLoop           ;jump if less than
```

The code is basically computing the 1/2 or 1/3 or 1/4 and adding it to a running sum, then compares to see if i've reached a value above what I entered, once it has it should exit the loop

do you guys see my error?

Comment: The final `jmp` is (logically) `jump if less than OR equal`. There's no good reason to use 387 code on x86-64. SSE is more orthogonal than the clumsy, stack-based ISA - and makes things like compares, etc., much easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [summation in assembly language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021071/summation-in-assembly-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems suspicious:

```
fst qword [currentSum]      ;pop current sum value into currentSum
```

contrary to the comment, `fst` stores the top of the stack into memory WITHOUT popping it.  You want `fstp` if you want to pop it.

Overall, the stack behavior of your program seems suspicious -- it pushes various things onto the fp stack but never pops anything.  After a couple of iterations, the stack will overflow and wrap around.  Depending on your settings, you'll then either get an exception or get bogus values if you don't have exceptions enabled.